# MySQL HOUR() starts at 6:30 instead of 6:00

Tags: mysql

How am I able to show results in MySQL using HOUR function or similar that can give me 6:30-7:30 instead of 6:00-7:00?

I'm using datetime and another column as int data type.

Here's sample data:

```
+----+--------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------+----------+-------------+
| id | data_uuid                            | date_time           | tool_id | param | position | data_count |
+----+--------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | 6f52b0b0-58c2-11e8-824e-af23caf3a508 | 2018-05-16 12:34:34 | DDS12   | L0    | LOADER   |           1 |
|  2 | 70243180-58c2-11e8-824e-af23caf3a508 | 2018-05-16 12:34:36 | DDS12   | U1    | UNLOADER |           1 |
|  3 | 70b7bef0-58c2-11e8-824e-af23caf3a508 | 2018-05-16 12:34:37 | DDS12   | L0    | LOADER   |           1 |
|  4 | 718b89b0-58c2-11e8-824e-af23caf3a508 | 2018-05-16 12:34:38 | DDS12   | U1    | UNLOADER |           1 |
|  5 | 7223f920-58c2-11e8-824e-af23caf3a508 | 2018-05-16 12:34:39 | DDS12   | L0    | LOADER   |           1 |
|  6 | 72feefd0-58c2-11e8-824e-af23caf3a508 | 2018-05-16 12:34:41 | DDS12   | U1    | UNLOADER |           1 |
```

What I want to see is something like this:

```
|    Hourly   | Qty |
| 6:30 - 7:30 | 245 |
| 7:30 - 8:30 | 134 |
```

Here's my query (I'm stuck):

```
SELECT HOUR(date_time), COUNT(data_count) AS Qty FROM table GROUP BY HOUR(date_time);
```

I'm thinking to use `>` and `<` but I guess there's something more efficient way to do it. I just don't know.

Thanks!

Comment: Please include sample data, table definitions and expected output in your question

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid: I included a query which I am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just subtract half an hour from the time in the table:

```
SELECT HOUR(date_time - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) AS thehour, COUNT(data_count) AS Qty FROM table GROUP BY thehour;
```

Btw you probably want `SUM(data_count)`, not `COUNT`.

Comment: Thanks Nick it works now!.  I'm just curious, why `SUM` and not `COUNT`?

Comment: I'm not sure how you're using `data_count`. If it's always 1 or `NULL` then `SUM` and `COUNT` will return the same value. If it's never `NULL`, `COUNT` will return a count of the number of rows in that hour, while `SUM` will return the sum of the `data_count` values for that hour. So whether you use `COUNT` or `SUM` depends on whether you want to just know how many `data_count` values were in the table for that hour (`COUNT`) or whether you want to know the sum of the `data_count` values for that hour (`SUM`).

Comment: I get it now. Thanks Nick.